# Get Flickr video player url from API call?

Tags: php, api, url, flickr

I'm trying to build the Flickr video player url from the flickr.photos.getInfo API call, but struggling very harshly. For one, I can't find any reference to the "v=xxxxx" part (as seen in the video player url, like so: http://www.flickr.com/apps/video/stewart.swf?v=71377&intl_lang=en-us&photo_secret=xxxx&photo_id=xxxx)

Second of all, do oyu guys have an idea about the 'stewart.swf' file? is this filename subject to change? it seems like an unconventional (but most certainly friendly) way to call your video player.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again, to answer my own question for future reference:

The stewart.swf has been around since (atleast) may 2010. We might suspect that this file will stay the same for the time being. However, the "v=71377" was "1.1xxx" back in may 2010. Therefor, this one *is* subject to change.

In other words, I will be hardcoding the stewart.swf and subsequently putting the v=xxxxx value in a config file.

Hope this helps somebody at some point.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the player url by calling [flickr.photos.getSizes](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getSizes.html) on a video. One of the sizes returned will be `Video Player` and its `source` attribute is the url you want.

Others sizes such as `Site MP4`, `Mobile MP4` and `HD MP4` may also appear.

More info on http://code.flickr.com/blog/2008/05/01/videos-in-the-flickr-api/